# Replace text with image Google Script?

Tags: javascript, image, api, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body?hl=en#getChildIndex%28Element%29) API to run an iteration over some Google Documents. However, I have very little experience concerning Javascript. How would I replace a keyword, say `<"image">`, with an actual inline image from a URL? Does ChildIndex support indexes within a paragraph? Bonus points for code!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add an actual inline image from a URL, try this:

```
var img_name_Url = "URL of the image";

var img_name_Blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(img_name).getBlob().setName("img_name_Blob");
```

In the document you want to use it in:

```
htmlBody : "The content for the inline image <img src='cid:img_name'>",
       inlineImages:
       {
         img: img_name_Blob
       }
```